# JAWS / Web-Aim Is there any way to specify text as "a time" for screen readers?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

If JAWS comes across a time in my page like so:

```
<div>
  <span>20:15</span> <!-- either of these times -->
  <span>04:15</span> <!-- either of these times -->
</div>
```

Then it reads them as "Twenty colon fifteen" which doesn't really sound like a time. Is there any way to specify that this is a time?

*Maybe* put text that is read but not seen by an average user as "Twenty colon fifteen o'clock" or something might be a viable answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to specify that this is a time?

HTML5 provides the [`time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) and its [`datetime` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#attr-time-datetime).

I can’t test if JAWS recognizes it, but it would be shame if it doesn’t (and they should certainly fix this).

For the time "20:15", the markup could be:

```html
<time>20:15</time> 
<!-- because "20:15" is a valid time string -->

<time datetime="20:15">20:15</time>
<!-- the datetime attribute is not needed here -->

<time datetime="20:15">…</time>
<!-- could have any content, as long as the datetime attribute contains a valid time string -->
```

Comment: This does not guarantee that the time will be spoken out any differently. The mapping to the accessibility APIs maps this purely as a static text http://www.w3.org/TR/html-aam-1.0/#el-time

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, you should be using the `<abbr>` element with a title attribute. The problem is that screen readers do not read out the abbreviation by default.

To get around this, you could use a combination of `aria-hidden` and off screen techniques such as:

```
  <span aria-hidden="true">20:15</span>
  <span class="offscreen">Twenty colon fifteen o'clock</span>
```

Where offscreen is:

```
.offscreen {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

According to the ARIA spec, these techniques should also work but (as with all ARIA) you need to test them to see whether they actually do work in practice

`<span aria-label="twenty hours and fifteen o'clock"><span aria-hidden="true">20:15</span></span>`

and

`<abbr title="twenty hours and fifteen o'clock" aria-label="twenty hours and fifteen o'clock">20:15</abbr>`

Comment: Thanks unobf, I used the abbr tag rather extensively the last few hours, found that to be a better solution than offscreen text.

Comment: @TaylorC.White did you test them?

Comment: Yeah, my screen reader doesn't read abbreviations by default but I turned it on and it reads fine.

Comment: If you are going to rely on that feature, you should put up an accessibility statement that informs users of the non-default settings they need in order to use your application. This should be included in the help and/or support area of the app/site